# Usage of "last leg"

Tags: phrases, expressions

Can I use the phrase "last leg" to refer to the last phase of some event? To be specific, if I want to say that I met someone towards the end of their journey (of months), can I say, I met him during the last legs of his trip?

Also, which proposition is appropriate: "in" the last legs or "during" the last legs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say in or during but it is last leg not last legs.

Comment: This should have been a comment...

Comment: @RoaringFish - because I answered concisely without adding confusing "other" facts?

Comment: That, and it is wrong. You can say *on* the last leg, but not *in* or *during*.   ->  http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+last+leg%2C+in+the+last+leg%2C+during+the+last+leg&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @RoaringFish - "In the last leg of the race I took over the lead."  Also... When did you take over the lead?  "During the last leg of the race."  Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, because the OP is asking about spatial location, a section of a journey - "towards the end of their journey", and you are giving examples of temporal location, describing when an event happened. Two different situations...

Comment: @RoaringFish - "I met someone during the last leg of my journey." and "I met someone in the last leg of his trip."  On could refer to a physical trip as Jim is alluding to.  In could refer to a specific time.  The trip could be in the same region and last 5 months... and you met someone in the last two weeks in their last leg of the trip.

Comment: Such nuanced doubts - and there are numerous every day - can be such a headache for us non-native speakers. If you guys are native English speakers then I am happy that it's not just us who has to deal with such confusions ;)

Comment: To be specific, my line is this: "X crashed at our place for few a nights (in/on/during/towards/while on) the last leg of his round the world trip."

Comment: I like towards - so as for our answers. None of the above.

Comment: Is *during* a time phrase or not? If it is, then none of your examples is referring to the situation of being on (not in or during) the last leg of anything. They are referring to completely different events during "*the last two weeks*" [=time] of a trip. You seem to be unclear about the difference between spatial reference and temporal reference; The OP is asking about how to refer to a stage of a journey and you keep giving examples of time phrases...  "Where is he?" "He is during the last leg of his trip" doesn't work because *during* is a temporal referent.

Comment: @RyeBread ~ some background on spatial/temporal referents in language: ~ http://www.fredonia.edu/studentexpo/eggpsy.htm ~ http://www.port.ac.uk/departments/academic/psychology/staff/downloads/filetodownload,68137,en.pdf ~ http://www.vyvevans.net/TFoRs.pdf ~ enjoy - it is an interesting topic.

Comment: @RoaringFish - you are missing the point.  I know all about the spatial/temporal/timewarp gibberish.  You are ASSUMING the OP is not referring to time by reading the question questionably and I believe that it could go either way.  I am not saying on is wrong, I am saying what I wrote can be correct too.  You refer to the journey as a physical trip but you don't know about it.  He could have had a 3 month journey covering 20 countries.  He stayed there for weeks 10-11 of 12 but during the 12th week went to 7 countries... "on" doesn't work there now but "in" does.  I am looking at it openly.

Comment: I apologize if my sentence was not clear enough. I was trying to use last leg more in the sense of last phase (thus temporal). The journey referred was more than a year long indeed involving perhaps more than 20 countries and may be one more after mine. also it was supposed to be *"a few nights" not "few a nights".

Comment: @Lavya ~ then you would be better not using "the last leg" as it is a spatial reference. A spatial reference can be used temporally if it is referred to as an experience: "while I was experiencing X, Y happened" as in "While I was experiencing (during) the last leg of the race, Y happened". This would be awkward for you as you didn't experience the last leg. "He stayed with us during the last leg of his trip" works as reported experience, but "I met him during the last leg of his trip" is awkward as you didn't 'endure' it. "I met him while he was on the last leg of his trip" is preferable.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. All were useful and were very informative and gave me a lot of pointers to think about. I have upvoted them all. Thanks for your times!!

Answer (score 5):

[***Leg***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leg) comes from:

> The part of an air route or a flight pattern that is between two successive stops, positions, or changes in direction.

So you should only use it when there actually were multiple legs in the trip.  If the person just went to Paris for 6 months and returned and you happened to meet him during his last week in Paris it would not be on the last leg of his trip.

However if his trip was to London, then Paris, then Milan, then Vienna, then Athens.  And you met him on the way from Vienna to Athens or maybe even in Athens then you met him in [or during] the last leg of his trip.

Comment: It has roots in running well before airplanes were invented.  I am sure other uses too.

Comment: @RyeBread- Of course.  It's the route between successive stops that's important.  The dictionary I quoted brought in airplanes unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can say that, but the individual will be *on* the last leg of their journey, in the same way that we are on the way home or on the way to the shop.

*In* or *during* are basically not used: [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20the%20last%20leg,%20in%20the%20last%20leg,%20during%20the%20last%20leg&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

There is also *on his last legs* that means the individual is very tired; his legs are about to collapse. For this reason, *on the final leg* of a journey is often used to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: In and during are used all the time.  Examples - "In the last leg of the race I took over the lead." Also... When did you take over the lead? "During the last leg of the race."   Ngram should not replace what we hear everyday nor logic.

Comment: Logic says that talking about space and talking about time are two different things. What we have here is Ngram saying one thing, based on a search of a huge corpus of books, and you saying another based on.... what?

Comment: To be specific, my line is this: "X crashed at our place for few a nights (in/on/during/towards/while on) the last leg of his round the world trip."

Comment: As "our place" is a spatial location, this should be matched with "on the last leg". Basically, you are answering "Where did he crash?"  If you want to use "towards", avoid using "the last leg" as "towards the last leg" means nearly on it, but not actually on it.